# How to let the div fill all of the remaining place?

Tags: css

This is my requirement:

[image]

How to let the panel fill all of the remaining place?

In my html:

```
<div style="height:48px; background-color:black; color:white;">
邓海波2
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:48px; bottom:0; left:0; width:200px;background-color:#333">
    <a class="menu" href="/app02/userinfo/">用户管理</a>
    <a class="menu" href="/app02/ugroup/">用户组管理</a>
</div>
<div id="div3" style="position:absolute; top:48px; left:200px;background-color:#eee">
...
</div>
```

This div3 style is need changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this styling to your div: `width: 100%;`.

This will take up 100% of its parent containers width.

And for future questions, please provide the full code. It’s disorienting seeing it without the `<li>`’s

Answer (score 0):

In your div3 add this

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

I change your code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/L63faL4a/2/